# How do I open a contact selection screen with "search by default"

Tags: android, android-contacts

How can I navigate to this screen using android intent

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- Add Read Contacts permissions.
- Use the code below.

  ```
  public void showContactsChooser(final View view){

   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
   startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
  }
  ```

We now get a screen that is showing us all the contacts we have. We choose one and we are getting back to our app.

To read this contact I am using this method:

```
  @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

        switch(reqCode){
           case (PICK_CONTACT):
             if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                 Uri contactData = data.getData();
                 Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(contactData, null, null, null, null);

                 if (c.moveToFirst()){
                 String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
             }
        }
    }
```

For further info use this link.
https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names